# Global variable and local variable conflicts

Tags: python

```
foo = 1
def bar():
    print(foo)
    foo = 5
```

This function throws UnboundLocalError: local variable 'foo' referenced before assignment.

My question is, how does the interpreter know that `foo` is a local variable in this function, what does the interpreter do before it excutes a function?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. In the future, you need to try your own research, like Googling the error message. I found that question and a bunch more by searching `"UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment"`. That said, kudos for writing a super clear and concise question!

Comment: Yet another reason to avoid global vars at all costs :) Check out this video, you might find it interesting - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9v8eu4MOet8